# Criação de um Código de Identificação com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

estou começando a trabalhar com programação agora e tenho bastante dúvidas. Estou precisando criar uma "TAG" específica para cadastro de equipamentos. Esta TAG precisa ter 4 letras + 4 dígitos, ex: CEME-0001.
As 04 primeiras letras referem-se ao setor que o equipamento esta localizado e os 4 números um valor a ser incrementado a cada novo cadastro. 
A letras do setores serão provenientes da tabela "tb_setores" do campo "sigla_setor".
Alguma ideia de como posso fazer uma código para executar esta ação ao cadastrar um equipamento?
Também vou precisar atualizar este campo, sendo possível transferir o equipamento de setor, que no caso mudará as letras e incrementará os números de acordo com a quantidade de equipamentos do setor transferido.

Comment: Poste a estrutura do seu banco de dados, provavelmente você nem precisará fazer nada a mais, dependendo de como estiver, você mantém esses dados (sigla-numero) em colunas diferentes e quando for buscar ou mostrar para o usuário só juntar

Comment: Bem-vindo Ronaldo Souza, aqui vai um post para que você obtenha sucesso nas suas próximas perguntas. Como criar um exemplo minimo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Importante também é marcar como aceita uma resposta que solucionou seu problema. Veja aqui como marcar uma resposta como aceita https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e aqui porque aceitar uma resposta

Answer (score 1):

> Como brinde de boas vindas vai uma resposta, nas suas próximas perguntas siga o post que recomendei no comentário da sua pergunta

```
//conexão ao banco
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "nome_DB");

//Letras dos setores recuperadas via post do formulário
$centro=$_POST["centro"];

/*seleciona um registro (limit 1) cujo as 4 primeiras letras são iguais
a variável acima na ordem descendente da coluna tag, que significa dizer, o maior, 
pois a parte das letras com tracinho são iguais e o que vai prevalecar na ordenação é
a parte numerica.******/    

$query = ("SELECT tag FROM cadastro WHERE LEFT(tag,4)='$centro' order by tag DESC limit 1");

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         //o registro
         $tag = $row["tag"];
         //separamos a parte numerica
         $num=substr($tag,5);
    } 

    /*****caso haja registro insere incrementando, caso contrário
    vai pro else inserir o primeiro******/
    if ($num!=""){
        //somamos 1 a parte numerica
        $proximo=($num+1);
        /**retorna o comprimento da variável acima, necessário pq o PHP ao somar 0001 + 1
        retorna 2, 0012 + 1 retorna 13, 0155 + 1 retorna 156  etc... dai 
        precisamos saber quantos zeros a esquerda serão necessários***/
        $comprimento=strlen($proximo);
        //quantidade e zeros necessários
        $zerosEsquerda = "4-$comprimento";
        // função responsável por colocar os zeros à esquerda
        $num = str_pad($proximo, $zerosEsquerda, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        // preparação do value da declaração insert
        $strProximo= $centro."-".$num;

        $conn->query("Insert into cadastro (tag) values ('".$strProximo."')");

    }else{

        $primeiro=$centro."-0001";
        $conn->query("Insert into cadastro (tag) values ('".$primeiro."')");

    }
```